# assign JavaScript cookie to a variable

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to assign a js cookie to a variable so that I can check if that cookie has been set or not:

```
(function(){
     var cookieSet = document.cookie ='cookie1=test';

     if (cookieSet == null) {
          console.log('hide');
     }
     if (cookieSet) {
         console.log('show');
          HB.BestBreakfast.showPanelAndHideOthers("commentBox");
     }

})();
```

however it's always showing 'show'.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Why would `document.cookie = 'x'` ever fail?

Answer (score 0):

```
var cookieSet = document.cookie ='cookie1=test';
```

This line assigns a value to `document.cookie`, then it assigns that value to `cookieSet`.

This means that `cookieSet` will **always** have a value.

Perhaps you want something like:

```
var cookieSet = document.cookie;
document.cookie ='cookie1=test';
```

So `cookieSet` gets the *old* value of `document.cookie` and *then* you assign a new value.

---

Additionally, if there are no cookies set, then `document.cookie` will be *an empty string* and not `null`.

You need to change your test to:

```
if (cookieSet == "") {
```

Comment: I have made that change and it's still showing 'show'

Comment: Have you deleted the existing cookie before reloading the page?

Comment: @Alex — You had another problem. Updated the answer.

Comment: still the same issue :(, I am using a chrome extension to delete the cookie but nothing at all..

Comment: Then examine the value of `document.cookie` and see what it actually is before you start manipulating it with JS.